# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

The dropdown is not showing, I won’t mind any assistance on what I’m doing wrong.

```
<div class=“boxOptions”>
    <div data-toggle=“dropdown” arial-haspopup=“true” arial-expanded=“false”>
        <i class=“fas fa-ellipsis-v”></i>
    </div>

    <div class=“dropdown-menu”>
        <a class=“dropdown-item” href=“#”>Activate</a>
        <a class=“dropdown-item” href=“#”>Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this.

```
           <div class="boxOptions dropdown">
                <div data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v'></i>
                </div>

                <div class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Activate</a>
                    <a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Try this one

Comment: The essence of .dropdown-toggle is to display the caret. Still not working that though but I appreciate your response.

Comment: I have updated the code after testing on my machine and above code is working very well. Try again once

Comment: And don't forget to add fontawesome cdn to make your icon visible. ignore it if already added